# The Twilight Zone: Only fiction show of the 1950s and 1960s to mention the current year?

Tags: the-twilight-zone

I am extremely familiar with the television of the 1950s and 1960s. For shows that were set in the present, unlike science fiction shows where they used the year (sometime laughably close, like less than 20 years hence) to establish that it was indeed set in the future, I am pretty sure that, for example, I Love Lucy never mentioned what year it was. They did have real-life movie stars in some episodes, playing themselves and I think even mentioning films they were working on which helped establish when the show was made but not only was the year never mentioned, the current president was not either. Same thing for Andy Griffith and Leave it to Beaver, etc.

My understanding is that this was to allow reruns to be show although I had thought that reruns, at least showing them in the distant future, was not planned -- they never anticipated that more than half a century later, many of the shows from the 1950 and 60s would continue to capture audiences whose parents might not have been alive when the shows originally aired.

The single exception that I know of is The Twilight Zone. Not every episode, maybe even infrequently but definitely sometimes, the actual year was mentioned. I can even recall an episode where LBJ is mentioned and this is while he was still VP -- I suspect this was the first time that LBJ was mentioned in a work of fiction. (I believe the episode was Hocus Pocus and Frisbee.)

Comment: Are you asking about shows fro the 1950s and 1960s specifically? Because I am quite certain there are dozens, if not hundreds, of TV shows that have mentioned the year and specific events in those years.

Comment: @ruffdove: i should have said, shows in the 1950s and 1960s. i suspect that later on, the years and current events might have been mentioned. i will edit question.

Comment: Usually the production year was shown in the __[end credits](https://youtu.be/M3XuEZVTvmM?t=50)__. For __[I dream of Jeannie](https://youtu.be/-dADf6q1QDs?t=23)__ it was even shown in the opening credits. So unless you cut the credits, it was clear from what year the show was.

Comment: @oliver_c: i of course meant in the story.

Answer (score -1):

**Modern era answer**

No. There are literally hundreds of shows that mention the then-current year or then-current events, and reruns are not a reason to not do so. A show episode set in 2013, even if 2013 was its original airing year, is still set in 2013 when you watch it in the year 2020. People are smart enough to know that a show set in modern times does not necessarily have to be set in the current year.

Many shows, in order to directly tackle real world events, HAVE to mention the then-current year in some form, like many shows at the time (1999-2000) did for new millennium celebrations, soap operas do for new years episodes and shows like South Park and The Simpsons do on a regular basis.

**1950-1960**

There was indeed a much more defined seperation between fictional and reality programming at the time, and this was a seperation that was expected by audiences at the time and for decades to come. This barrier was infamously broken in the 1992 British horror mockumentary, Ghostwatch, where many people were convinced that the events taking place in the film were real and one teenager even committed suicide as a result. This was primarily because the show was broadcast on TV by the BBC, took the form of a news broadcast format and primarily featured famous real-life BBC broadcasters, and at no point called itself a 'drama' or anything like that.

The closest I can think of is A Hard Days Night, a film (not a TV series) starring the Beatles as themselves in a mockumentary style film made in 1964 at the height of Beatlemania. Their popularity and how they clashed with common British culture at the time does date this film to around about this time, if not to an exact year.

Comment: yes, i should have said and have now edited the question to be limited to 1950s and 1960s. it was not so hard, with only 3 channels, to know almost every tv show in those days and i can't recall a show made in that periods beside TZ that would mention the current year.

Comment: @releseabe ok, I've updated my answer :)

Comment: i don'[t know why you would mention a movie -- many movies made before the 1950s mention is either explicitly or implicitly the year, like Best Year of Our Lives is plainly set in late 1945. I am asking about TV series made in the 1950s and 1960s.